# multiple joins and group by in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, group-by

I'm using Codeigniter, what I want to do is a query that returns users by groups.

A group can have one or more users, here examples of the tables:

```
groups table        users table              users_by_groups table
    id                  id                    id_group   id_user
    1                   10                      1          10
    2                   11                      1          11
    3                   12                      1          12
                                                2          11
                                                3          12
```

the query I made:

```
public function getUsersByGroup(){
        $this->db->select('g.vgro_name,u.vusr_user');
        $this->db->from('vts_user_by_group b');
        $this->db->join('vts_groups g', 'b.vubg_vgro_id = g.vgro_id');
        $this->db->join('vts_users u', 'b.vubg_vusr_id = u.vusr_id');
        $this->db->group_by('g.vgro_name,vusr_user');
        // $this->db->order_by('u.vusr_user','asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

what this is returning:

```
      0 => 
object(stdClass)[28]
  public 'vgro_name' => string 'GROUP1' (length=4)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'john' (length=9)
1 => 
object(stdClass)[29]
  public 'vgro_name' => string 'GROUP1' (length=4)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'alice' (length=4)
2 => 
object(stdClass)[30]
  public 'vgro_name' => string 'GROUP2' (length=3)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'mark' (length=3)
```

which is not what I want. What I pretend is for example:

```
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[31]
  public 'vgro_name' => string 'GROUP1' (length=7)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'john' (length=7)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'alice' (length=7)

    2 => 
object(stdClass)[30]
  public 'vgro_name' => string 'GROUP2' (length=3)
  public 'vusr_user' => string 'mark' (length=3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're expecting to be able to flexibly add columns to the output of a sql query, where in reality you can only really add rows.

Comment: But adding another user will be a row, not a column...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the 'grouping' in PHP:

```
public function getUsersByGroup(){
    $this->db->select('g.vgro_name,u.vusr_user');
    $this->db->from('vts_user_by_group b');
    $this->db->join('vts_groups g', 'b.vubg_vgro_id = g.vgro_id');
    $this->db->join('vts_users u', 'b.vubg_vusr_id = u.vusr_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $resultsByGroup = array();

    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $resultsByGroup[$row['vgro_name']][] = $row['vusr_user'];
    }

    return $resultsByGroup;
}
```

Comment: is it not possible doing this with sql? Your code works perfect, only one line is missing before the loop: $query = $this->db->get();

Comment: @Limon it's not possible to stack the results into arrays of groups via sql

Comment: is that because I have more than 1 join? If I had 1 join it will work, I think

Comment: @Limon no, it's not because of your joins. sql simply can not organize results into arrays - it's always a list and it's up to the application to sort that list into groups of arrays. `group by` is used for aggregation and not grouping into arrays